# previous_posts_link returning blank values

Tags: wordpress

I am sing the below mentioned code to navigate between my posts but the previous and next posts link doesn't show anything and just returns blank on the browser.

I am using the below mentioned code on my index.php and single.php page after the loop is closed.

**index.php: and single.php**

```
   <div class="navi">
        <div class="right">
            <?php previous_posts_link('Previous'); ?> / <?php next_posts_link('Next'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Expected result:**

Previous / Next

But I am getting
**Result:**

/

Am I missing something here.

Comment: It should be in the loop `while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); <?php previous_posts_link('Previous'); ?>  etc`

Comment: No. What I am trying to achieve here is a single previous/next link at the bottom of my page. So, they must exist outside of the loop. And I just read somewhere that they work outside of loop also.

But still I gave it a try and the code doesn't show anything even if I put it  inside of the loop. So, I guess there is something else wrong here

Comment: I use it inside of my loop for single.php where I want to toggle between posts. but in index.php I am using it outside of loop to toggle between pages of posts not individual posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add `$the_query->max_num_pages` in function `next_posts_link()` and set `$the_query` variable as per your query.

```
// the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php

// next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
```

Comment: @Mihai this function has two argument.please check